# How to choose from available iso files on boot?

Tags: partitioning, iso-image, bootloader

What I want to achieve is I want to be able to choose (either by available iso files or menu entries, which you need to enter yourself, doesn't really matter) the iso file (image of an actual operating system - mainly Windows 10) and run it.
I imagine the partition of the HDD would consist of two partitions, the boot manager partition and another big partition where you can put the iso files.

**My question:**

Is there a way to achieve that?
The container file doesn't need to be explicitly an iso, it can be any other container file.

I had a look at rEFind (http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) but I'm not sure or better to say I haven't found anything regarding iso support or my special case

Comment: [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)?

Comment: @CaldeiraG Unfortunately, GRUB would call the Windows Boot Manager, which won't be installed.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Hehe no, you're right I didn't mean that and edited my question; I meant any other container file :)

Answer (score 0):

You can mount an ISO using loopbacks on GRUB. However, this only works on GRUB 2. You would need to have GRUB already installed on your hard drive or on a USB.

To do this, you first need to find the location of your ISO on your Windows drive. For now, let's say the location is `C:\Users\varun\Downloads\Windows.iso`Then when you have that, you would run the following in a GRUB2 terminal:

```
insmod part_msdos #allows you to access MBR partitions (if you have GPT, use gpt in place of msdos)
insmod ntfs # allows you to access NTFS filesystem
loopback loop (hd0,1)/Users/varun/Downloads/Windows.iso # mounts ISO on a loop device
```

For (hd0,1), the name can vary. It depends on which drive and partition your Windows partition is on the drive. The above means the first partition (1) on the first hard drive (hd0). Note that hard drives start from 0, and partitions start from 1. Also, your partition number may or may not be prefaced by a gpt or msdos; just check which one is your windows partition and substitute accordingly.

Now that you mounted the iso using a loopback, you can access it using `ls (loop)\`. Find the location of the Windows bootloader; it should be at `(loop)/efi/Microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi`. Chainload that bootloader, and it should boot the iso when you type boot after.

Note that the following only works if you're on a UEFI system or a system that supports UEFI boot.